# PHP URL configuring

Tags: php

I have a quick question.

```
<a href="#/media/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>.<?php echo $row['news_title'] ?>">Read More</a>
```

Basically, it'll show my URL once I click on "Read More". I added the

```
.<?php echo $row['news_title'] ?>
```

before the `">`

basically, it'll show `ID.THE-TITLE-HERE`

However, it's not working, it does work when i manually add in the "-" in the url for the article after the ".", but it doesn't work.

You'll see what I mean if you go to http://www.krissales.com/#/media/blog

hit "Read More" and it wont show anything, but if you add a "-" between "testing" and "2" it'll work.

Would anyone know how I could go about fixing this? Just tell me what I can do, I wanna learn at the same time while doing it.

the full .php page is at krissales.com/blog.txt

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, replace the spaces in `$row['news_title']` with `-`'s as required.... The content is now not `ID.THE-TITLE-HERE` but `ID.THE TITLE HERE`

Comment: Why not add the "-" in the $row['news_title'] using str_replace()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$row['id']` is 99 and `$row['news_title']` is "The title" then the following code will use `str_replace` to output "99.The-title".

```
<a href="#/media/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>.<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", $row['news_title']); ?>">Read More</a>
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I've read all of what you said, I'm still learning, but I see what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
echo $row['news_title']
```

To

```
echo str_replace(" ","-",$row['news_title']);
```

This will replace the white space with hyphen

Answer (score 2):

I noticed someone else gave the simple answer while I was typing this, but I think my answer will help you understand a bit further.

First the tests:

- "http://www.krissales.com/media/3" works
- "http://www.krissales.com/#/media/3" works
- "http://www.krissales.com/#/media/3.Testing 3" does not works.
- "http://www.krissales.com/#/media/3.Testing-3" works.
- "http://www.krissales.com/#/media/3.Testing%203" works (%20 being the URL Encoded equivalent of a space).

The problem is probably how you handle the hash tag, etc.

First, with what I know, you could get it to works multiple way:

1. Instead of:
   `<?php echo $row['news_title'] ?>`
   You could use
   `<?php echo urlencode($row['news_title']) ?>`
   Which will make sure there is no space used.
2. If you prefer to replace space with dash, then you can use str_replace() function (http://www.php.net/str_replace) like this:
   `<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $row['news_title']); ?>`

This will work, however, I do not feel this fix the problem at core, which is probably where you handle the call (code in your /_lib/_js/core.js file), etc.

P.S. You will want to make sure you escape URL variable, HTML content, etc. -- see these function in PHP urlencode(), htmlspecialchars() -- but if you build code with other language (like javascript), the same logic apply.  This might somehow hide a core problems in your code with how you handle URL, etc.  It is the source of multiple problems in software development. ;-)